# Codeigniter - não consigo imprimir os valores do select na view

Tags: php, codeigniter

Boas, eu estou a tentar fazer uma página em que mostra os dados do utilizador que está logado.

Model:

```
function getAllDisplayable3()
 {
     $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
     $this->db->select('id_login, nome, username, password, cod_postal, telefone, email, localidade, rua');
     $this->db->from('login');
     $this->db->where('username', $username);
     $result = $this->db->get();
     //echo $username; echo die();
 }
```

Fiz o echo do $username e imprimiu.

```
<input class="form-control" id="nome" value="<?php echo $perfil->nome?>" type="text">
```

E dá erro: Undefined variable: perfil. O que tenho que colocar para imprimir os valores?

Obrigada.

Comment: Faltou o return na função

Comment: @Andre Bail eu já coloquei o return no final da função: `return $result->result();`. No entanto, continuo com o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 2):

Seus dados precisam passar pelo controller primeiro para depois serem repassados para view.

**Model**

```
function getAllDisplayable3() {
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $this->db->select('id_login, nome, username, password, cod_postal, telefone, email, localidade, rua');
    $this->db->from('login');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    return $this->db->get();
}
```

**Controller**

```
class Formulario extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('perfil'); // Nome do model

        // Faz a chamada da função
        $dados = $this->perfil->getAllDisplayable3(); 

        // Envia os dados recebidos para a view
        $this->load->view('formulario', $dados);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<input class="form-control" id="nome" value="<?php echo $perfil; ?>" type="text">
```

Comment: Boas @Vinicios, eu tenho controller, mas como penso que não seja importante para o problema não coloquei. O meu controller é o seguinte:
`function perfil()
 {
  $this->load->model('perfil_model');
  $data['list'] = $this->perfil_model->getAllDisplayable3();
  $data['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
  $this->load->view('perfil_view',$data);
 }`

Comment: após criar a variavel "$data['list']" use um "var_dump($data['list']); exit;" e verifique o valor retornado.

Comment: @Vinicious Yals retornou-me um array com os valores todos `array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#21 (9) { ["id_login"]=> string(2) "23" ["nome"]=> string(4) "lola" ["username"]=> string(3) "lol" ["password"]=> string(3) "lol" ["cod_postal"]=> NULL ["telefone"]=> NULL ["email"]=> NULL ["localidade"]=> NULL ["rua"]=> NULL } }`

Comment: @Viniciuous Yals , já resolvi o problema. Era na view, faltava o foreach. Obrigada